# React wrapper: React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a wrapper component around the react-router-dom `NavLink` component.

I would like my custom component to accept all of NavLinks props, and proxy them down to `NavLink`.

However when I do this, I'm getting:

> Warning: React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM
>   element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom
>   attribute, spell it as lowercase `staticcontext` instead. If you
>   accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM
>   element.

A working demo of the issue can be found here:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/w0n49rw7kw

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There is a way to overcome that is using:

```
const { to, staticContext, ...rest } = this.props;
```

So your `...rest` will never contain `staticContext`

Comment: how to find it in a huge codebase though, i can't check all the props

Comment: @AmineDa. sorry I don't have the answer for this. You can create a new question a mention this post. Maybe, someone with more experience than me can help.

Answer (score 30):

This is a common problem with a simple solution as documented in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html):

> The unknown-prop warning will fire if you attempt to render a DOM
>   element with a prop that is not recognized by React as a legal DOM
>   attribute/property. You should ensure that your DOM elements do not
>   have spurious props floating around.
>
> The spread operator can be used to pull variables off props, and put
>   the remaining props into a variable.

```
function MyDiv(props) {
  const { layout, ...rest } = props
  if (layout === 'horizontal') {
    return <div {...rest} style={getHorizontalStyle()} />
  } else {
    return <div {...rest} style={getVerticalStyle()} />
  }
}
```

> You can also assign the props to a new object and delete the keys that
>   you’re using from the new object. Be sure not to delete the props from
>   the original this.props object, since that object should be considered
>   immutable.

```
function MyDiv(props) {

  const divProps = Object.assign({}, props);
  delete divProps.layout;

  if (props.layout === 'horizontal') {
    return <div {...divProps} style={getHorizontalStyle()} />
  } else {
    return <div {...divProps} style={getVerticalStyle()} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

This happens because you probably used `{...props}` somewhere in your component.

Example from [React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html):

```
function MyDiv(props) {
  const { layout, ...rest } = props
  if (layout === 'horizontal') {
    return <div {...rest} style={getHorizontalStyle()} />
  } else {
    return <div {...rest} style={getVerticalStyle()} />
  }
}
```

We grab `layout` separately so that it won't be contained in `{...rest}`.

Answer (score 3):

The given answer by the React docs was not quite good enough for my situation, so I found/developed one which isn't perfect, but is at least not so much of a hassle.

You can see the Q/A in which it arose here:
[What is Reacts function for checking if a property applies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977515/what-is-reacts-function-for-checking-if-a-property-applies/50978965#50978965)

The gist is, use a function to pick the bad props out for you.

```
const SPECIAL_PROPS = [
    "key",
    "children",
    "dangerouslySetInnerHTML",
];

const defaultTester = document.createElement("div")
function filterBadProps(props: any, tester: HTMLElement = defaultTester) {
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') { return props; }

    // filter out any keys which don't exist in reacts special props, or the tester.
    const out: any = {};
    Object.keys(props).filter((propName) => 
        (propName in tester) || (propName.toLowerCase() in tester) || SPECIAL_PROPS.includes(propName)
    ).forEach((key) => out[key] = props[key]);

    return out;
}
```

Personally, I felt that the warning was completely useless in the first place, so I added a line which skips the check entirely when not in development mode (and warnings are suppressed).  If you feel that the warnings have merit, just remove the line:

`if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') { return props; }`

You can use it like this:

```
public render() {
    const tooManyProps = this.props;
    const justTheRightPropsForDiv = filterBadProps(tooManyProps);
    const justTheRightPropsForSpan = filterBadProps(tooManyProps, document.createElement("span"));

    return (<div {...justTheRightPropsForDiv}>
        <span {...justTheRightPropsForSpan} />
    </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when passing data in child component with camelCase property.

> Warning: React does not recognize the `moreInfo` prop on a DOM element.
> If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute,
> spell it as lowercase `moreinfo` instead. If you accidentally passed it
> from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

```
 <CenteredModal
      moreInfo={viewType}
 />
```

To fix that error, I used all lowercase letters for property.

```
 <CenteredModal
      moreinfo={viewType}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has this issue with react-admin, check if you don't have a Link as a child of Admin. Like this:

```
<Admin layout={props => <Layout/>}>
  <Link to="/something">something</Link> <-- causing issue
</Admin>
```

Just move it to another component. For instance, inside the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

use lowercase for renaming the prop instead of camelcase or uppercase.